# Which key does the e.metaKey refer to in JavaScript MouseEvent?

Tags: javascript, browser, mouseevent, dom-events, keycode

`MouseEvent.metaKey` doesn't seem to work. On both FireFox and Chrome, it returns `false` even if I hold the <kbd>Win</kbd> key while clicking:

```html
<!doctype html>
<button onclick=alert(event.metaKey)>click while holding "meta key"</button>
```

MDN [states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/metaKey):

> The `MouseEvent.metaKey` read-only property returning a [*`Boolean`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) that
>   indicates if the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key was pressed (*`true`*) or not (*`false`*) when the
>   event occured.
>
> Note: On Macintosh keyboards, this is the command key (<kbd>⌘</kbd>). On Windows
>   keyboards, this is the windows key (<kbd>⊞</kbd>).
>
> #### Browser Compatibility
>
> [image]

MDN claims `MouseEvent.metaKey` is supported on FireFox and Chrome, but it's not working.

Which key does  `MouseEvent.metaKey`  refer to?

Why is the above code not working?

Answer (score 12):

If you're asking which key you would have to press on a Windows system in order for the `MouseEvent`'s `metaKey` property to be `true`, the answer is that it depends on the browser. And some Windows browsers simply don't support it and always return `false` or `undefined`.

I could not find an up-to-date chart of browser support for `metaKey`, though there is a really [old one at QuirksMode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_events.html#keyprops).

If you are using jQuery, `metaKey` is one of the event properties that [it normalizes for cross-browser compatibility](http://api.jquery.com/event.metaKey/).

If you need to implement a key + mouse event for some functionality on your website, I would use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, so that it works on all systems. (If you need more than one key option, I would suggest you rethink your design.)

Comment: It's still not working. (Btw, I've updated the question.)

Answer (score 4):

Empirical testing, shows the following results.  Not that jQuery doesn't do a terribly good job of normalizing ^F.

On a Mac, in Safari Version 5.1.7 & 6.0.

```
 F   Keypress: 102, 102  
⌘F   Keypress: 102, 102  meta 
⌥F   Keypress: 402, 402  alt 
⌃F   Keypress: 6, 6  ctrl
⇧F   Keypress: 70, 70  shift
```

On a Mac, in Firefox 15.0.1:

```
 F   Keypress: 102, 0
⌘F   Keypress: 102, 0 meta 
⌥F   Keypress: 402, 0 alt
⌃F   Keypress: 102, 0 ctrl
⇧F   Keypress: 70, 0 shift
```

On a Mac, in Google Chrome 18.0.1024.168:

```
 F   Keypress: 102, 102
⌘F   (No triggers sent for ⌘ + key)
⌥F   Keypress: 402, 402 alt
⌃F   Keypress: 6, 6 ctrl
⇧F   Keypress: 70, 70 shift
```

Test code:
      // jquery-1.7.2

```
  $(document.defaultView).keypress(function(e) {
      console.log("Keypress: " + e.which + ", " + e.keyCode, " "
          + (e.metaKey ? "meta " : "")
          + (e.ctrlKey ? "ctrl " : "")
          + (e.altKey ? "alt " : "")
          + (e.shiftKey ? "shift " : ""));
  });
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. Did you actually manage to get the value as `true`?

Comment: @Pacerier - My tests were with the keypress event, not a mouse event, my bad.

Comment: @Pacerier - Some testing with Chrome on OS X show the same results as I specified for Safari,  metaKey is set when ⌘ is depressed.

Answer (score 1):

> Which key does MouseEvent.metaKey refer to?

It refers to the windows key <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>

> Why is the above code not working?

Because of a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1266437) as of at least Firefox 48, see the [docs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1266437) for more infos.

#### A solution :

Use the <kbd>shiftKey</kbd> instead. Which has a property with the same name on the event object.