# How can I make event.metaKey work?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I've been trying to use [event.metaKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.metaKey), but I can't capture it (the ctrl, shift and alt versions work perfectly). I use the following script to catch it and it want it to evaluate to true when when I press the Windows button.

```
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
   alert(event.metaKey);
}
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bruno91/8fAE7/).

It's hinted that it doesn't work in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245868/which-key-does-the-e-metakey-refer-to-in-javascript-mouseevent).
Is there any way to make it work?
edit: I don't know whether it matters, but I only need it to work for firefox (addon).

Comment: You are very unlikely to implement usage of the Windows key cross-browser. I'd use a different key.

Comment: I only need it to work for firefox (it's an addon) and I really need the amount of permutations four modifier keys give me.

Comment: @Kvothe In Firefox under Linux you can use `event.keyCode == 0` to detect that Win is pressed, but I'm not sure if it will work for a modifier key. See [here](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) for more details.